# I am developing a application using JAVA & GTK+ on UBUNTU 14.04 64 bit OS . But continuously getting exception in loading the glade file

Tags: java, exception, gtk, glade, gdk

I am getting exception while running. It compiles correctly but can't start application. So how can i handle this exception and run my code.
 The Exception is:

> DANGER: 
>   Gdk-WARNING, gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
>  Exception
>   in thread "main" org.gnome.glib.FatalError: Gdk-WARNING
>   gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large     at
>   org.gnome.gtk.GtkWidget.gtk_widget_show_all(Native Method)    at
>   org.gnome.gtk.GtkWidget.showAll(GtkWidget.java:541)   at
>   org.gnome.gtk.Widget.showAll(Widget.java:182)     at
>   ExamplePressMe.Main.main(Main.java:23) .

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="name">XYZ Copier</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">XYZ Copier</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">520</property>
    <property name="default_height">150</property>
    <property name="icon">icon.png</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_top">4</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">4</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="margin_left">3</property>
                <property name="margin_right">16</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Total Progress :</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label6">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="margin_left">2</property>
                <property name="margin_right">2</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Moving file 5  of 10 (220 Mb of 1230 Mb)</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">2</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkProgressBar" id="progressbar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">5</property>
            <property name="pulse_step">0</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">2</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid3">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_top">4</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">4</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkSeparator" id="separator1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label3">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="xpad">3</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Current progress :</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label4">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Moving  XYZ to PQR</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">3</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="label5">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="xalign">0</property>
                <property name="yalign">1</property>
                <property name="xpad">14</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Speed : 24 Mbps</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">5</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkSeparator" id="separator2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">2</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkSeparator" id="separator3">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">4</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">2</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkProgressBar" id="progressbar2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">4</property>
            <property name="position">4</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid4">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_top">4</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">4</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Skip Current File</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="margin_left">40</property>
                <property name="margin_right">40</property>
                <property name="relief">half</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Pause Copying</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="margin_left">40</property>
                <property name="margin_right">40</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">2</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button3">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Stop Copying</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="margin_left">40</property>
                <property name="margin_right">40</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">4</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                <property name="width">1</property>
                <property name="height">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="padding">2</property>
            <property name="position">5</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

and JAVA file is

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Window w;
    Builder b;
    Gtk.init(args);
    b = new Builder();
    try {
        b.addFromFile("Mycopy.glade");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    w=(Window) b.getObject("window1");
    w.showAll();
    Gtk.main();
    }
}

</code>
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: failed to start my application.

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: how to get rid of this exception and launch app .

Comment: So, first we need to uncover what "too large" means: the size of the icon file is too large, or the size, or sizes, of the icons themselves is too large.  What is the size of your icon file in bytes, and can you post an image of your icon file?  Also, I'm referencing this documentation here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html.  What version of Gnome are you running, if indeed you are running Gnome?

Comment: the size of icon file 38.7 KB. i am running ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: Taking a stepwise approach to solving the problem, then, swap out the contents of your current .png file with a file containing a single 16x16 image.  Is your current .png file a sprite by any chance?

Comment: Thanks , After removing icon app started running but i wan't to add the icon so i will try after resizing.

Comment: Excellent!  We're making progress...